# Project Euler #21

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop

Condition :

> Let d(n) be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n).
>   If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, where a ≠ b, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.
>
> Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.

I did the following :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        long sum = 0;
        List<int> passedValues = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var number1 = SumOfNumber(i);
            var number2 = SumOfNumber(SumOfNumber(i));
            if (number2 == i && !passedValues.Contains(number1))
            {
                sum = sum + number1;
                passedValues.Add(number1);
                passedValues.Add(number2);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int SumOfNumber(int input)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= input/2; i++)
        {
            if (input%i == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

however it gives result 40284 while the correct answer seems to be 31626 why is my program not working properly ? Am I adding something multiple times ? I also tried adding a list to store the passed values, however it ended up giving a result 25008 :

```
static void Main()
    {
        long sum = 0;
        List<int> passed = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var number1 = SumOfNumber(i);
            var number2 = SumOfNumber(SumOfNumber(i));
            if (number2 == i && !passed.Contains(i))
            {
                sum = sum + number1;
                passed.Add(number1);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-21-sum-of-amicable-pairs/

Comment: If I wanted to copy paste some code I was not going to post here for help

Comment: Well to put short, your code is just not solving the problem. Step through it and you'll find out why. You should find the culprit with less than ten f10 keystrokes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You are not adding *both* amicable pair numbers to the sum.
2. You are including perfect numbers (where d(n) = n), which don't qualify as amicable pairs because a ≠ b is violated.

I think you were closer when you didn't add in the list to store passed numbers, because that caused issue #1 above since you are adding only the contribution of `number1` to the sum, but adding both `number1` and `number2` to the list, causing `number2` to eventually get skipped.  To address issue #2, you also need to validate `number1 != number2`.  For example:

```
if (number2 == i && number1 != number2)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this check
{
    sum = sum + i;
```

After applying both of these fixes to your provided code, I am getting the expected total of 31626.

Comment: I removed the `passedValues` entirely because it is unnecessary.  You are only seeing each value once, so there should not be any duplicates.  However, you do want to add `i` or `number2`, NOT `number1`.  Think about the case where a < 10000 and b > 10000.  You would be adding `b` to the total but it doesn't satisfy the condition that you are adding amicable numbers < 10000.  Fortunately no amicable pairs have one number < 10000 and one > 10000 so this is not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

I got the result as 31626. The difference here is how to prevent duplicate in the sum. Instead of saving into a list, just to make sure i is always less than number1.

```
 static void Main()
    {

        long sum = 0;
        List<int> passedValues = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var number1 = SumOfNumber(i);
            var number2 = SumOfNumber(SumOfNumber(i));


            if (number2 == i && i < number1)
            {
                sum = sum + i + number1;

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum );
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int SumOfNumber(int input)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= input / 2; i++)
        {
            if (input % i == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: This is a good solution too, avoiding both perfect numbers and duplicates nicely! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int SumOfNumber(int input)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= input/2; i++)
    {
        if (input%i == 0)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is not correct. You are only adding one of the factors, and not looping up to the sqrt of the number.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, another algorithm is to factorize first, then find all possible divisors via recursion on the map of factors & their powers.

It can be much quicker, when n becomes large, e.g n = `100_000`.

---

### Code (`go`)

**amicable_number.go**:

```
package p21

import (
    "math"
)

// refer:   https://projecteuler.net/problem=21
/*
Let d(n) be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n).
If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, where a ≠ b, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.

For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.

Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.
*/
// find sum of all amicable numbers < n
func FindAmicableNumberSum(n int, excludeSame bool) int {
    dm := FindAmicableNumber(n, excludeSame)
    sum := 0
    for k, v := range dm {
        if k != v {
            sum += k
        }
    }
    return sum
}

// find all amicable numbers < n, in map's key, map's value is the other pair,
func FindAmicableNumber(n int, excludeSame bool) map[int]int {
    dsm := FindAllDivisorSum(n)
    am := make(map[int]int)
    for k, v := range dsm {
        if v2, ok := dsm[v]; ok && k == v2 {
            if excludeSame && k == v {
                continue
            }
            am[k] = v
            am[v] = k
        }
    }
    return am
}

// find divisor sum for all number x < n, divisor include 1, exclude x itself,
func FindAllDivisorSum(n int) map[int]int {
    ps := FindPrimeTillN(n + 1)
    dm := make(map[int]int)
    for x := 2; x < n; x++ {
        ks, fm := findFactorMap(x, ps)
        sum := divisorSum(ks, fm) - x
        dm[x] = sum
    }
    return dm
}

// find divisor sum of x, divisor include 1, exclude x itself,
func FindDivisorSum(x int) int {
    ps := FindPrimeTillN(x + 1)
    ks, fm := findFactorMap(x, ps)
    return divisorSum(ks, fm) - x
}

// factorize x, with given prime cache,
func findFactorMap(x int, ps []int) ([]int, map[int]int) {
    fm := make(map[int]int)
    var ks []int
    for i := 0; i < len(ps) && x > 1; i++ {
        p := ps[i]
        e := 0
        for x%p == 0 {
            x /= p
            e++
        }
        if e > 0 {
            ks = append(ks, p)
            fm[p] = e
        }
    }
    return ks, fm
}

// sum of all divisor, include 1 and x itself,
// tip:
// - to avoid clone of ks slice & fm map, and keep 2 branch don't affect each other,
//   should recover ks slice & fm map before return,
//   thus ks & fm are not change after calling the function,
func divisorSum(ks []int, fm map[int]int) int {
    // fmt.Printf("%v, %v\n", ks, fm)
    if len(ks) == 1 {
        p := ks[0]
        e := fm[p]
        sum := 1
        for i, d := 1, p; i <= e; i, d = i+1, d*p {
            sum += d
        }
        return sum
    }

    fp := ks[0]
    fe := fm[fp]
    if fe == 0 { // x=0, formula: f(a^0 * ..) = f(..)
        delete(fm, fp)
        result := divisorSum(ks[1:], fm)
        fm[fp] = fe // recover
        return result
    } else if fe == 1 { // x=1, formula: f(a^1 * ..) = (a+1) * f(..)
        delete(fm, fp)
        result := (fp + 1) * divisorSum(ks[1:], fm)
        fm[fp] = fe // recover
        return result
    } else { // x>=2, formula: f(a^x * ..) = a^x * f(..) + f(a^(x-1) * ..)
        fm[fp]--
        right := divisorSum(ks, fm)
        fm[fp]++ // recover

        delete(fm, fp)
        left := int(math.Pow(float64(fp), float64(fe))) * divisorSum(ks[1:], fm)
        fm[fp] = fe // recover

        return left + right
    }
}

// find all primes < n
func FindPrimeTillN(n int) []int {
    var ps []int
outer:
    for x := 2; x < n; x++ {
        max := int(math.Sqrt(float64(x)))
        for i := 0; i < len(ps) && ps[i] <= max; i++ {
            if x%ps[i] == 0 {
                continue outer
            }
        }
        ps = append(ps, x)
    }
    return ps
}
```

**amicable_number_test.go** *(Test case)*:

```
package p21

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
)

func TestFindAmicableNumberSum(t *testing.T) {
    sumExcludeSame := FindAmicableNumberSum(10_000, false)
    fmt.Printf("10000 (include same = %v) -> sum: %d\n", false, sumExcludeSame)
    assert.Equal(t, 31626, sumExcludeSame)
}

func TestFindAmicableNumberSumLarge(t *testing.T) {
    // n = 100_000, takes 1s,
    // fmt.Printf("100_000 (include same = %v) -> sum: %d\n", false, FindAmicableNumberSum(100_000, false))

    // n = 1_000_000, takes 57s,
    // fmt.Printf("1_000_000 (include same = %v) -> sum: %d\n", false, FindAmicableNumberSum(1_000_000, false))
}

func TestFindAmicableNumber(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Printf("10_000 (include same = %v) -> pairs: %d\n", true, FindAmicableNumber(10_000, true))
    fmt.Printf("10_000 (include same = %v) -> pairs: %d\n", false, FindAmicableNumber(10_000, false))
}

func TestFindDivisorSum(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Printf("30 -> %d\n", FindDivisorSum(30))
    fmt.Printf("220 -> %d\n", FindDivisorSum(220))
    fmt.Printf("284 -> %d\n", FindDivisorSum(284))
    fmt.Printf("1184 -> %d\n", FindDivisorSum(1184))
    fmt.Printf("1210 -> %d\n", FindDivisorSum(1210))
}
```

To run the test, need to add `testify` via:

> go get -u github.com/stretchr/testify

---

### Speed

This is much quicker than brute force used in the question, here is my test result *(running on an old laptop)*:

- With factorize & recursion (aka. the code above):

  - n = `10_000`, sum = `31626`, takes `0.02` second.
  - n = `100_000`, sum = `852810`, takes `0.97` second.
  - n = `1_000_000`, sum = `25275024`, takes `57` seconds.
    It can be further optimized I think, since, it's still slow for `1_000_000`.
- With brute force (aka. code similar as in the question):

  - n = `10_000`, sum = `31626`, takes `0.38` second.
  - n = `100_000`, sum = `852810`, takes `38` seconds.
  - n = `1_000_000`, it takes too long, I stopped before it would finish.

---

### Tips

- The function `FindAmicableNumberSum()` accepts a flag `excludeSame` to indicate whether exclude numbers that make `d(n) = n`.
  For `Project Euler #21` it should always be set to `true`.